# Easyui - SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical

Tags: javascript, datagrid, jquery-easyui

based on that [a link](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/app/crud3.php)!, I'm trying adapt this code to my project. however when I click save this error appears:

> SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical Warning: main(): It is not
>   safe to rely on the system's timezone se

My js

```
function saveItem(index) {
    var row = $('#dgusu').datagrid('getRows')[index];
    var url = row.isNewRecord ? 'app/cadusuarios_acao.php?opcao=C' :
        'app/cadusuarios_acao.php?opcao=A?id=' + row.id;
    $('#dgusu').datagrid('getRowDetail', index).find('form').form('submit', {
        url: url,
        onSubmit: function () {
            return $(this).form('validate');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            data = eval('(' + data + ')');
            data.isNewRecord = false;
            $('#dgusu').datagrid('collapseRow', index);
            $('#dgusu').datagrid('updateRow', {
                index: index,
                row: data
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Someone can tell me where I am going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Looks like the code has all parentehes, please check `data` before evaling it.

Comment: I don't see any missing parenthesis in the code you posted, though you should really format your code better.  Are you sure it's happening there?  Does it say what line number the error is on?

Comment: jquery-1.6.min.js (linha 56, col 7) after this error appear this!